# Windows Phone Keep Previous Installation

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to keep the former installation and its references' DLL files? I tried but it uninstalled first and then copied new DLL files to the former location. I have changed the publisher and product ID in the `WMAppManifest` XML. But encountered unexpected results (wp8 Silverlight project).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

If you are trying to keep installation files for an app that is published in the store, you can't. But there are some ways to do that:

1. Get store application pure XAP file and use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/). And do what you want, your previous installation files are safe. Run your project and you will see that you get the data from the previous one.
2. It won't work unless you publish your new XAP to the store. Theoretically, it will work (I haven't tested). This method does not allow you to test the process locally. You can only suppose that it will work after publishing.